# How do int color codes in android work?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following problem:

I have a list view, I want to assign a gradient color to item separator ( Divider) of this list view. I am using the following code:

```
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    int[] colors = { 0, 0xffffff00, 0 }; 
    list.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
    list.setDividerHeight(4);
```

I looked up the color code (0xffffff00) from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

***PROBLEM:***

However this color is Yellow, what I want is golden. I am also interested to know how this works, I mean how can I define the color of my choice, so far I tried to understand from the developer site but it is not much clear.

Comment: [colorpicker](http://www.colorpicker.com/)

Comment: How to use these color values in terms of ff? I am confused at that part!

Comment: As @blackbelt said first ff is alpha component, more like for transparency purpose, ff is fully opaque and 00 for transparent. So, FFC0C0C0 is fully opaque gray color and 00C0C0C0 is transparent gray color. So, use color codes from site mentioned above preceeded by transparency bits.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that you wrote is the hex notation. You can think about a color as composed of 4 components. ARGB. In your example you have 0xffffff00. The first ff is the alpha component, the second ff is the red component, the third ff is green component the fourth 00 is the blue component. Change those hexadecimal values you can get your colors.

Use

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 175, 64);
```

or use an iteger to hex converter

Comment: Okay I have an RGB color:
R:255
G:175
B:64

How do I repressent it in terms of ff?

Comment: Bingo!! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

For gold you need a yellow that's more red than green, so try 0xffffc000. In decimal that would be red 255 green 192 blue 0. To really get a hold of how the RGB system works spend a while playing with the values, I don't think it's possible to get a deep understanding just by reading about it.

Comment: Yes I am utterly confused how ff works and what values to convert RGB into to get an ff representation. Thanks let me try this out!

Comment: You are asking how to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal? Divide by 16: the quotient is the first digit and the remainder is the second. Write A,B,.. for 10, 11, .. Since division by 16 is not easy in mental arithmetic it's better to just forget decimal and get used to hexadecimal